# Good way to call overloaded const vs non-const method in C++ TDD?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, catch-unit-test

All

wrote some fancy container with iterators. So I have

```
iterator begin() {
}

iterator end() {
}

const_iterator begin() const {
}

const_iterator end() const {
}
```

In test I instantiate container, fill it and testing it. What is an accepted/good way to call both const and non-const version? Say, simple test like

```
TEST( c.end() - c.begin() == c.size() );
```

should run for iterators as well as for const iterators.
Const reference? Some ugly cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just make a const& to it:

```
const container& constC= c;
TEST(constC.end() - constC.begin() == constC.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think not overloading them is a better solution as per `std` convention.

Declare `cbegin()` and `cend()` instead.

Comment: the std convention is to do all of the above: `iterator begin();`, `const_iterator begin() const;`, and `const_iterator cbegin() const;`